# How secure Laravel private channels are?

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I don't understand how do the private channels in Laravel work.

When I listen to a private channel:

```
window.Echo.private('activity')
    .listen('ActivityCreated', (e) => {
        console.log("Activity Created", e);
    }
);
```

Laravel makes a request on `/broadcasting/auth/` to verify my backend allows my frontend to listen to this socket. The exchanged information is some encrypted information.

What I don't understand is that anybody can subscribe to any channel:

```
./pusher channels apps --app-id=12345678 --channel=private-activity subscribe
Successfully subscribed to channel 'private-activity'.
Event: channel=private-activity event=App\Events\ActivityCreated message=[]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: for private channel `channels.php` here write all security layer  like `return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yeah I know that but I don’t know how this security layer works

Comment: it just check if return true then allows to connect that channel so here validate right person join right channel

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes, but behind the scene, what prevent the client to subscribe to the Pusher socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Echo isn't more than a wrapper to the Pusher Library [UTSL](https://github.com/laravel/echo). Behind the scenes, you have the Pusher app well documented [here](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users)

Pusher will only allow connections to private Channels after the request being signed from your server `routes/channels.php`. Once your backend has allowed the client to access the channel it just JWT the authorization back to the client which then forwards it as the access key to Pusher through the WSS.

Even if your transmission is compromised you should not be vulnerable to a MITM attack because.

[image]

Comment: In terms of subscribing to the channel, that's restricted to only the authenticated user. When it comes to the messages being transmitted, those can be intercepted by a middle-man (unless they're encrypted).